# Set size on Selectize.js

Tags: selectize.js

Couldn't find any example or help at [Selectize.js](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) I really don't know if its possible, but I wold like to set it size like a normal `Html` select tag before the user choose an option.

```html
<select class="Campo" id="selMedicacao" name="selMedicacao" size="5"> 
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
  <option value="5">Option 5</option>
  <option value="6">Option 6</option>
  <option value="7">Option 7</option>
  <option value="8">Option 8</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to create on an `tab click` event

```
$("#aProcedimento").on('click', function () {
    funPesProcPaciente(document.frmProcedimento);
});
```

the `element` after selectize.js script ran

```
function funPesProcPaciente(objForm) {
  var strXML = '../xxx/xxxxxxxxxx.xml.asp?cabxml=s&paciente=' + 
  $('#intPaciente').val();
  var selProcPaciente = document.createElement("SELECT");
  funMontaComboXMLHistorico(document.getElementById('xmlProcedimento'), selProcPaciente, strXML, 'procedimento', 'A', 'numero', 'A', 'texto', 0, 0, document, '');
  selProcPaciente.setAttribute('size', '7');
  selProcPaciente.setAttribute('class', 'divPedido'); 
  selProcPaciente.setAttribute('id', 'divPedido'); 
  objselProcPaciente = document.getElementById('selProcPaciente')
  objselProcPaciente.innerHTML = '';
  objselProcPaciente.appendChild(selProcPaciente);
  strXML, 'requisicao', 'A', 'numero', 'A', 'texto', 0, 0, document);
}
```

[image]